# Proper use of ||

Tags: javascript

The general question I suppose is: when does || return the item on the left, and when does it return the item on the right?

The specific question, is why doesn't this work:

```
var fibonacci = (function () {

    var cache = [0, 1];

    function fibonacci(number) {
        return cache[number] = cache[number] || (fibnonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2));
    }

    return fibonacci;
})();

var $div = $('div');

for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    $('<span />').text(fibonacci(index))
        .appendTo($div);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It returns the item on the left if and only if it is truthy.

The following are not truthy:

- The primitive boolean value `false`
- The primitive string value `""` (the empty string)
- the numbers +0, -0 and `NaN`
- the primitive value `null`
- the primitive value `undefined`

Everything else is truthy.

[Here is the list on the language specification](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2).

In your case `cache[0]` returns 0 which as we can see is falsy so it enters recursion. This is why we avoid `||` for short circuiting in these situations.

You should consider checking directly that the object has that property: `number in cache` is one such way and another is `cache[number] !== undefined`.

Comment: Shouldn't cache[0] return a value then? For some reason it just gives me a StackOverflow (tm).

Comment: @sircodesalot Because `cache[0]` is `0` which is falsy and so it goes into an infinite recursion (because `cache[x]` for negative `x` is `undefined`, i.e. falsy as well).

Comment: @sircodesalot no, fibonacci(0) is falsy which means it calls the recursion. This is _exactly_ why we avoid `||` (and more generally 'truthyness') in these situations. Just use `cache[number]===undefined`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum As I've mentioned the real problem is not that `cache[0]` is falsy but rather that `cache[x]` for negative `x` is falsy hence the infinite recursion.

Comment: @freakish Right, but we only check cache[x] for negative x _because_ cache[0] is falsy. If it wasn't falsy we wouldn't be in that position in the first place (like you mention in your comment) :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you can't use the value in cache when it's 0 as `0 || func()` asks for the function to be called.

So it always call the second term for 0 and thus makes a stack overflow as the recursion has no end.

A solution would be to change your internal function like this :

```
function fibnonacci(number) {
    if (number in cache) return cache[number];
    return cache[number] = fibnonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2);
}
```

As an aside please note the spelling of [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: Ah crap. So `cache[0]` is falsy, and therefore it calls recursion?

Comment: Yes, it's an endless recursion.

Comment: Perfect, this works like a charm. Heh, didn't notice the misspelling, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the first `true` from the left. If no `true` it returns `false`. If the expressions resolve to true, in case of a Boolean or a non-zero or non-null or non-undefined value.

### Edit:

Yes, the value has to be truthy...not only true.

Comment: It doesn't have to be `true`... just "truthy".