# What does || mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean-operations

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. What does `||` do?

Comment: mean or   ...........

Comment: Search for ["javascript operators"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) (this works for most any language .. and Java != JavaScript).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036171/proper-use-of

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation

Comment: Do you mean `Java || JavaScript`? (ps- it means "OR")

Comment: [Become a search ninja](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22||%22)

Comment: @minitech Cool, thanks for the heads-up about quotes (now?) working on symbols.

Comment: Become a search ninja... or maybe just read a JavaScript book.

Answer (score 2):

It is a condition operator, meaning “or”, typically used like this:

```
if (browserIsMSIE || browserIsFirefox) {
  …
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[MDN Expressions and Logical statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)

> (Logical OR) Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

```
var o1 =  true || true;     // t || t returns true
var o2 = false || true;     // f || t returns true
var o3 =  true || false;    // t || f returns true
var o4 = false || (3 == 4); // f || f returns false
var o5 = "Cat" || "Dog";    // t || t returns Cat
var o6 = false || "Cat";    // f || t returns Cat
var o7 = "Cat" || false;    // t || f returns Cat
```

Answer (score 1):

If something1 **or** something2, do something: equates to this

```
if (something1 || something2){
    ... do something
}
```

If something1 **and** something2, do something: equates to this

```
if (something1 && something2){
    ... do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's same as in other C type languages. A Logical Operator, for the OR condition.

Here's the Docs on Mozilla Developer Network.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators